# How to add many fields with ng-switch (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-switch

I have two nested ng-repeat,and i wanted to add the same form **MiseEnContext** many times,inside this "MiseEncontext" i wanted to add some inputs, but when i add text it's added for all my **MiseEnContext**
Question:
How to isolate my **MiseEncontext** ?

```
'<h4>Exercice Redactionnel</h4>\
                    <ul>\
                        <li><a ng-click="addMiseEnContext()">Mise en context</a></li>\
                        <li><a ng-click="addQuestion()">Question</a></li>\
                    </ul>\
                    <div ng-repeat="exRedContent in exRedContents">\
                        <div ng-switch on={{exRedContentType}}>\
                            <div ng-switch-when="1">\
                                <h5>Mise en context</h5>\
                                    Titre<input type="text" /><br />\
                                        <button ng-click="addTexte(1)">addText</button>\
                                    <div ng-repeat="MecField in MecFields">\
                                        <div ng-switch on={{fieldsType}}>\
                                                <div ng-switch-when="1">\
                                            Text<input type="text">\
                                        </div>\
                                            <div ng-switch-when="2">\
                                                  <h5>Text illustré</h5></ br>\
                                                  Position: <input type="radio" name="group1" value="droit" checked>Text à droite<br />\
                                            </div>\
                                     </div>\
                            </div>\
                          </div>\
                        <div ng-switch-when="2">\
                                <h5>Question</h5>\
                            </div>\
                    </div>\
                  </div>'
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Cr0WN4hCuKTYJOfb5CBf?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you are using `$scope.MecFields` as share able `$scope` variable in you directive. I'd love to make it separate via adding index to that object so that it will become unique/separate array for each `ng-repeat` element. The array content would depend on there index.

**Markup**

```
<button ng-click="addTexte($index)">addText</button>\
<div ng-repeat="MecField in MecFields[$index]">\
    <div ng-switch on={{fieldsType}}>\
        <div ng-switch-when="1">\ Text
            <input type="text">\
        </div>\
        <div ng-switch-when="2">\
            <h5>Text illustré</h5></ br>\ Position:
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="droit" checked>Text à droite
            <br />\
        </div>\
    </div>\
</div>\
```

**Code**

```
$scope.addTexte = function(index) {
  $scope.fieldsType = $scope.types[0].id;
  if (!$scope.MecFields[index]) $scope.MecFields[index] = [];
  $scope.MecFields[index].push({
    field: '',
    value: ''
  });
};
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PYLOItutRw7OIT6SfPDX?p=preview)